# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning : error handling in an async callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have an async callback function, which throws an error if some condition isn't met.

but I get the below error

> (node:77284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not Found

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

My Code :

```js
async deleteItem(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const ref = firestoreDB.collection("items").doc(id);

    firestoreDB
      .runTransaction(async (transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
        let doc = await transaction.get(ref);
        if (doc.exists) {
          transaction.delete(ref);
        } else {
          throw new NotFoundException();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof NotFoundException) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          throw new HttpException(
            "Something went wrong",
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
          );
        }
      });
  }
```

What is the proper way to throw an error from the callback function?

Comment: try to wrap your async callback function implementation inside try...catch

Comment: Maybe you forgot `await` before `transaction.delete(ref);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at code examples for `.runTransaction()`, it looks like it returns a promise and will propagate a promise rejections from its callback (that's a bit of a different interface for a plain callback), but in any case, it looks like you just need to return the promise from `firestoreDB.runTransaction()` from your `deleteItem()` method and then make sure the caller of that method is using `.catch()` to handler any errors.

```
async deleteItem(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const ref = firestoreDB.collection("items").doc(id);

    // add return here
    return firestoreDB
      .runTransaction(async (transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
        let doc = await transaction.get(ref);
        if (doc.exists) {
          transaction.delete(ref);
        } else {
          throw new NotFoundException();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof NotFoundException) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          throw new HttpException(
            "Something went wrong",
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
          );
        }
      });
  }
```

Then, wherever you call `.deleteItem()`:

```
obj.deleteItem(...).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. The caller of the function is a Nest.js rest controller which returns the service method, so it'll handle the propagation of the http error. Returning the transaction promise solved the problem.